# WCF Metadata not available when browsing directly

Tags: .net, wcf, metadata

When I browse to the .svc I continually get the error: Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.

I have followed all of the instructions listed on the error page (added the behavior, referenced the behavior, added the mex endpoint, tried both with and without baseaddress), along with the instructions on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734765.aspx (pretty much the same, but include the policyversion). I even gutted my config file and only left this stuff - it just doesn't make any difference at all. I've confirmed that the config file is being used (i.e. make a mistake in it, and the error changes).

Section looks like:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="HoldingService" behaviorConfiguration="SimpleServiceBehavior">
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost/xxxx.cdf.holding/HoldingService.svc"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <endpoint address=""
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                contract="Xxx.Xxxx.Schema.Service.Cdf.Holding.IHoldingService" />
      <endpoint address="mex"
                binding="mexHttpBinding"
                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="SimpleServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" policyVersion="Policy15" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Is there any way at all to fix or debug this?

Comment: FWIW, system is WinXP running IIS 5.1 and VS2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to resolve this. The problem was `name="HoldingService"`. Even though the .svc is in the same project as the .config, it needed to be fully qualified (i.e. `name="Xxx.Xxxx.Web.Cdf.Holding.HoldingService"`).

The final code looks like this and works perfectly:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="Xxx.Xxxx.Web.Cdf.Holding.HoldingService" behaviorConfiguration="SimpleServiceBehavior">
      <endpoint address=""
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                contract="Xxx.Xxxx.Schema.Service.Cdf.Holding.IHoldingService" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="SimpleServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

As an aside, the way I ended up resolving this was by using the "Microsoft Service Configuration Editor" (accessible via `Tools` > `WCF Service Configuration Editor` in VS2010). I didn't know this existed and had been hand-cutting the config.

Thanks Michael for your suggestions - they cleaned the code up a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Might be silly, but try taking away the policy version from your serviceMetadata behavior. I've never seen this needed. You can also remove the mex endpoint and just browse to...

```
http://localhost/xxxx.cdf.holding/HoldingService.svc
```

The mex endpoint is for things like metadata exchange over named pipes and such. As long as you have an http endpoint, that should do.

Also, since you're hosting in IIS, it looks like the base address is probably not being used. Just drop that section and go to where ever you have the svc file in IIS.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I used them to clean up the code a lot.

Comment: Cool. Did it fix the MEX issues?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I did manage to solve it in the end. It hadn't dawned on me that I needed to fully qualify the service name. Obvious in hindsight (as the config file isn't in the service's namespace)!